# QT crash caused by QNetworkReply *

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I'm trying to make a get request but getting the segfault in the RELEASE build mode. In the debug mode everything is working just fine.

Here is the code:

**RequestsPerformer**

```
bool RequestsPerformer::perform(const Request &req)
{
    qDebug() << "RequestsPerformer::perform url = " << req.url;
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(req.url);

    for (const auto &key : req.headers.keys())
    {
        request.setRawHeader(key.toUtf8(), req.headers.value(key).toUtf8());
    }

    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Mobile Safari/537.36");

    qDebug() << "RequestsPerformer::perform getting reply for " << req.url;
    QNetworkAccessManager * am = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    QNetworkReply * reply = /*Model::MainModel::networkAccessManager()*/am->get(request);

    qDebug() << "RequestsPerformer::perform connecting reply for " << req.url;
    //connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &RequestsPerformer::onFinished);
    //connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::errorOccurred, this, &RequestsPerformer::onFailed);
    qDebug() << "RequestsPerformer::perform done for " << req.url;
} <- app crashes after this method is done
```

**Using RequestsPerformer**

```
void SpotDataStorage::update()
{
    ...
    Common::RequestsPerformer * requestPerformer = new Common::RequestsPerformer();
    
    QObject::connect(requestPerformer, QOverload<const QJsonObject &>::of(&Common::RequestsPerformer::finished), this, &SpotDataStorage::onUpdateRequestFinished);
    QObject::connect(requestPerformer, &Common::RequestsPerformer::failed, this, [=](){
        qDebug() << "SpotDataStorage request failed";
        requestPerformer->deleteLater();
    });

    requestPerformer->perform(req);
    qDebug() << "SpotDataStorage::update called perform request for " << service->name();
}
```

App output:

```
RequestsPerformer::perform url =  QUrl("https://api.coincap.io/v2/markets?quoteId=tether&limit=500&exchangeId=binance")
RequestsPerformer::perform getting reply for  QUrl("https://api.coincap.io/v2/markets?quoteId=tether&limit=500&exchangeId=binance")
RequestsPerformer::perform connecting reply for  QUrl("https://api.coincap.io/v2/markets?quoteId=tether&limit=500&exchangeId=binance")
RequestsPerformer::perform done for  QUrl("https://api.coincap.io/v2/markets?quoteId=tether&limit=500&exchangeId=binance")
**Crash**
```

Message "SpotDataStorage::update called perform request for " is not printed

Any ideas?

Comment: I do not want to suggest that this is the cause of the crash, but aren't you leaking `QNetworkAccessManager`?

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R isn't that code enough? I will append crash stacktrace tonight, but a bit later

Comment: @HiFilethebestfilemanager yes, with the temporary solution just for example I am using (am = new QNetwork...) and not deleting it, but in the real code i'm using static method to get needed pointer and deleting it as needed